# After Changing Github User Name?

Tags: github

After you change your github username, are there github settings that you need to change?

Comment: From what I remember, you'll have to update all of your cloned repositories as well if you want to push changes.

Answer (score 0):

See the [reference link](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username) for updating

All references to the previous username, such as old url with your name  will now give a 404 error. We cannot set up a redirect from the old username to the new one.